In i3 how to bind Control+Shift+V to also do Paste?
In i3 Shift+Insert does Paste.
How do I in .config/i3/config bind
Control+Shift+V to also do Paste?
Yes, there are plenty of partial answers out there.

You can bind it to a CLI that'll paste. For example, I use clipit and can ask i3 to bind to the appropriate CLI that comes with said package:
bindsym Ctrl+Shift+v exec --no-startup-id clipaste


Also discussed in https://github.com/i3/i3/discussions/6348
